# Magento 2 full page cache problem

Tags: magento2, full-page-cache

I've written a function that after logging in, an group image will show to customer according to their groups. However, I found that after logging in, no images show to the customers if full page cache is turned on. The images can only show to the customers when the full page cache is disabled.

How can I deal with this issue?

Comment: Hi Ricky any findings on this??

Answer (score 1):

**`controller_front_send_response_before`**

This event will be fired irrespective of FPC enabled. Try using observer on this event.